# Can't send word documents (.doc and .docx) as email attachment from form

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm trying to send an email with an attachment from a form to myself. This works succesfully when I add a .pdf file as an attachment. But it fails when I try a .doc or .docx file.

I've added some validation in javascript, but that accepts every file type I need:

```
var validFileTypes = ["doc", "docx", "pdf", "tiff"];
```

This is my **c#** code to check my form and send the email:

```
private bool SendJobMail()
    {
        var client = new MailerServiceReference.IemailClient();
        var succeeded = false;

        string _recipient = "jobs@company.eu";
        string _firstName = firstName.Value;
        string _lastName = lastName.Value;
        string _telNr = phone.Value;
        string _motivation = motivation.Value;
        string _sender = "info@company.eu";


        int vacId = Int32.Parse(vacancyId.Value);
        string vacTitle = _vacancies.Find(vac => vac.Id == vacId).Title;
        string subject = string.Format("Application from {0} {1} for {2}", _firstName, _lastName, vacTitle);

        _motivation += string.Format("\n\n{0}{1}\n{2}\n{3}", _firstName, _lastName, email.Value, _telNr);

        //set up and add an attachment
        string attachmentFilename = Path.GetFileName(cv.PostedFile.FileName);
        Attachment attachment = new Attachment(cv.FileContent, attachmentFilename, MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet); //can interpret PDF and richtextdocument

        ContentDisposition disposition = attachment.ContentDisposition; //disposition necessary for some mailing applications
        disposition.CreationDate = File.GetCreationTime(attachmentFilename);
        disposition.ModificationDate = File.GetLastWriteTime(attachmentFilename);
        disposition.ReadDate = File.GetLastAccessTime(attachmentFilename);
        disposition.FileName = Path.GetFileName(attachmentFilename);
        disposition.Size = cv.PostedFile.ContentLength;
        disposition.DispositionType = DispositionTypeNames.Attachment;

        try
        {
            client.Open();
            client.SendEmail("CompanyPublicSite", _sender, _recipient, subject, _motivation);
            succeeded = true;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            client.Close();
        }

        return succeeded;
    }
```

If you need any additional code, let me know.

Comment: What is "it fails"? What _does_ happen? There's nothing special to .doc(x) as opposed to PDF, all formats are binary data and should be treated as such (which you do using `MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet`). The exact exception message will tell you what is wrong.

Comment: Sorry good question, the email gets sent, but without the attachment. It just stays blank. The rest of the information (name, email, etc..) arrives at the recipient though.

Comment: That's the hard part for me to figure out. There's no exception that tells me anything.

Comment: This code won't work for PDF either, as you never attach the attachment to the mail. We can't tell how you do so, I'm sure your company has some internal documentation on how to use `MailerServiceReference.IemailClient`.

Comment: Oh, it does work for PDF. I added the code bit that uses the MailerServiceReference.IemailClient. But I don't think there's anything fishy with that..

Comment: No, it doesn't. This code does nothing with `attachment` or `disposition` other than assign some properties. They do not get sent to the mailservice. Either some code you didn't show does that, or you didn't test _this_ code with a PDF file.

Comment: Oh.. Yeah, you're right. The PDF never came through.. Well I managed to fix it by using an SMTPClient which is a hell of a lot easier to add attachments to.

Comment: Good you got it figured out!